# VS Code Platform-IO configuration

Tags: ide

I had been using Platform-IO up to 2019 but when I reopened a project things started getting worse and worse. Tasks disappeared and it took a while to be able to compile again. Now Platform-IO has disappeared completely and I was getting deprecation warnings in the "Toggle developer tool' console.
Now after a complete reinstall of VS, Platform-IO etc. the IDE is still not functioning and I regret ever using it. It is like you jump into your car begging it to start. For professional use (able to restart your car every day without a mechanics) this solution needed to be solid and reliable which it does not seem to be. I will have to switch to another IDE I guess. The name Microsoft should have make me hesitate ...

I am using Windows 7 Professional and NO I WILL NOT UPGRADE THE OS.

Is there any means to install a functioning VS-Code / Platform-IO on Windows 7 or is it just an idea of an IDE ?

Sorry to appear mean but "Making you more productive" sounds like a scorn.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried installing Platform IO on a Win 7 PC of a colleague and experienced similar issues like you. Seems like current Platform IO versions / builds are not compatible and therefore not runnable on Windows 7.

Only idea comes to my mind is using legacy / previous releases of VS Code and Platform IO (manual plugin installation with a legacy release) to get a runnable environment on Win 7, but I didn't test it since I ended up installing a recent Ubuntu next to Win 7. (Seemed like a better solution to me).

Here you can find all of the older releases of VS Code & Platform IO:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_previous-release-versions
- https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64
- https://github.com/platformio/platformio-core/releases

Good luck ;)